# Bcrypt implementation I wrote returns the correct cost and salt, but the encrypted message is incorrect

Tags: c, cryptography, bcrypt

First, a bit of background. I'm a member of the TI (calculator) programming community, and I've been writing a cryptography library for the TI-84+ CE. My latest endeavor was to add to this project a function to hash a password using bcrypt.

This algorithm generates the correct cost count and salt, but the ciphered message portion is wrong, and I've tried many different modifications of the salting process in the LoadKey routine to no avail, before finally deciding to post on here for assistance. I suspect the issue is with how I mix in the salt because I have verified the Blowfish cipher itself working (ECB mode) if only a key and no salt is provided, and in the output hash, the cost and salt both encode/decode correctly. If the key expansion works to generate a valid cipher when there is no salt, that kind of leaves the salt as the source of the error, I believe.

If anyone can assist me in debugging this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:
hashlib_BlowfishInit() sets the P and S block initial states
hashlib_RandomBytes() invokes a CSPRNG I wrote for this lib

```
// hash a new password if verify==NULL, or return true/false for password match if verify is not NULL
bool hashlib_PasswdBcrypt(uint8_t* bcrypt, const uint8_t* passwd, const uint8_t* verify, BLOWFISH_KEY* ctx){
    uint24_t cost = 0, rounds;
    uint8_t salt[16] = {0};
    uint8_t* magic = "OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt";
    size_t mstringlen = strlen(magic);
    size_t pstringlen = strlen(passwd);
    uint8_t bcrypt_out[24] = {0};
    if(pstringlen>72) return false;
    // If verify is NULL, initialize new hash, else, hash with same parameters as one to verify
    if(verify==NULL){
        hashlib_RandomBytes(&salt, 16);
        cost = 12;
    } else {
        hashlib_b64decode(&salt, 16, verify+7);
        for(uint8_t i=4; verify[i] != '$'; i++){
            cost *= 10;
            cost += (verify[i]-'0');
        }
    }
    
    // key expansion rounds = pow(2, cost)
    rounds = 1<<cost;

    hashlib_BlowfishInit(ctx);
    
    // how many rounds do you want? ALL THE ROUNDS!!
    hashlib_BlowfishLoadKey(passwd, &salt, ctx, pstringlen);
    for(uint24_t i=0; i<rounds; i++){
        hashlib_BlowfishLoadKey(passwd, NULL, ctx, pstringlen);
        hashlib_BlowfishLoadKey(&salt, NULL, ctx, 16);
    }
    
    // encrypt magic string 64x
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        hashlib_BlowfishEncrypt(&bcrypt_out, magic, ctx, mstringlen);
        memcpy(magic, &bcrypt_out, 24);
    }
 
    // write output
    sprintf(bcrypt, "$2a$%u$", cost);
    hashlib_b64encode(bcrypt+7, &salt, 16);
    hashlib_b64encode(bcrypt+7+22, &bcrypt_out, 24);
    bcrypt[7+22+31] = '\0';
    if(verify == NULL) return true;
    if(strncmp(bcrypt+3, verify+3, 57)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This is the key expansion code, derived from bcon's crypto algorithms

```
void hashlib_BlowfishLoadKey(const BYTE user_key[], const BYTE salt[], BLOWFISH_KEY *keystruct, size_t len)
{
    BYTE block[8];
    int idx,idx2;

   // Combine the key with the P box. Assume key is standard 448 bits (56 bytes) or less.
    for (idx = 0, idx2 = 0; idx < 18; ++idx, idx2 += 4)
        keystruct->p[idx] ^= (((uint32_t)user_key[idx2 % len]) << 24) | (((uint32_t)user_key[(idx2+1) % len]) << 16)
                           | (((uint32_t)user_key[(idx2+2) % len]) << 8) | ((uint32_t)user_key[(idx2+3) % len]);
   // Re-calculate the P box.
    memset(block, 0, 8);
    for (idx = 0; idx < 18; idx += 2) {
        if(salt){
            uint8_t salt_segment_start = (idx%4==0) ? 0 : 8;
            for(uint8_t salty=0; salty<8; salty++)
                block[salty] ^= salt[salt_segment_start + salty];
        }
        hashlib_BlowfishEncryptBlock(block,block,keystruct);
        keystruct->p[idx] = (((uint32_t)block[0]) << 24) | (((uint32_t)block[1]) << 16) | (((uint32_t)block[2]) << 8) | block[3];
        keystruct->p[idx+1]=(((uint32_t)block[4]) << 24) | (((uint32_t)block[5]) << 16) | (((uint32_t)block[6]) << 8) | block[7];
    }
    // Recalculate the S-boxes.
    for (idx = 0; idx < 4; ++idx) {
        for (idx2 = 0; idx2 < 256; idx2 += 2) {
            if(salt){
                uint8_t salt_segment_start = (idx2%4==0) ? 0 : 8;
                for(uint8_t salty=0; salty<8; salty++)
                    block[salty] ^= salt[salt_segment_start + salty];
            }
            hashlib_BlowfishEncryptBlock(block,block,keystruct);
            keystruct->s[idx][idx2] = (((uint32_t)block[0]) << 24) | (((uint32_t)block[1]) << 16) |
                                   (((uint32_t)block[2]) << 8) | block[3];
            keystruct->s[idx][idx2+1] = (((uint32_t)block[4]) << 24) | (((uint32_t)block[5]) << 16) |
                                     (((uint32_t)block[6]) << 8) | block[7];
        }
    }
}
```

I'll also provide the base64 routines I use as well, however I know these are not the problem, as with the salt, they encode and decode the salt properly, as evidenced by it being the same in the test hash and in the computed one.

```
static const uint8_t Base64Code[] =
"./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
#define CHAR64(c)  ( (c) > 127 ? 255 : index_64[(c)])
static const uint8_t index_64[128] = {
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 1, 54, 55,
    56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
    51, 52, 53, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
};
bool hashlib_b64encode(char *b64buffer, const uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
    uint8_t *bp = b64buffer;
    const uint8_t *p = data;
    uint8_t c1, c2;

    while (p < data + len) {
        c1 = *p++;
        *bp++ = Base64Code[(c1 >> 2)];
        c1 = (c1 & 0x03) << 4;
        if (p >= data + len) {
            *bp++ = Base64Code[c1];
            break;
        }
        c2 = *p++;
        c1 |= (c2 >> 4) & 0x0f;
        *bp++ = Base64Code[c1];
        c1 = (c2 & 0x0f) << 2;
        if (p >= data + len) {
            *bp++ = Base64Code[c1];
            break;
        }
        c2 = *p++;
        c1 |= (c2 >> 6) & 0x03;
        *bp++ = Base64Code[c1];
        *bp++ = Base64Code[c2 & 0x3f];
    }
    *bp = '\0';
    return true;
}

bool hashlib_b64decode(uint8_t *buffer, size_t len, const char *b64data)
{
    uint8_t *bp = buffer;
    const uint8_t *p = b64data;
    uint8_t c1, c2, c3, c4;

    while (bp < buffer + len) {
        c1 = CHAR64(*p);
        /* Invalid data */
        if (c1 == 255)
            return false;

        c2 = CHAR64(*(p + 1));
        if (c2 == 255)
            return false;

        *bp++ = (c1 << 2) | ((c2 & 0x30) >> 4);
        if (bp >= buffer + len)
            break;

        c3 = CHAR64(*(p + 2));
        if (c3 == 255)
            return false;

        *bp++ = ((c2 & 0x0f) << 4) | ((c3 & 0x3c) >> 2);
        if (bp >= buffer + len)
            break;

        c4 = CHAR64(*(p + 3));
        if (c4 == 255)
            return false;
        *bp++ = ((c3 & 0x03) << 6) | c4;

        p += 4;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the output of the test hash and the computed hash, indicating some portions of it generate correctly but not others.

```
Test:     $2y$04$Rv/h.CQCHOrfwmFBaq2due3mmvUnuClwalb7A2F84DfhjQLxtaVmu
Computed: $2a$04$Rv/h.CQCHOrfwmFBaq2dueEuQwVqKCW4gEqJdOQH4QltVnFfSOAOE
```

Comment: Update on above question: (1) I had my base64 encoding wrong actually. Apparently bcrypt uses a slightly different encoding table. I have fixed and tested this against an online b64 encoder. (2) Still unsure if I'm hashing properly, but if I am, the output of this is still wrong. However, the blowfish works. I know this because I am able to encrypt a message using a secret 32-bit key, and the python blowfish module is able to load that key and decrypt the message. Thus I don't believe the problem is in the blowfish implementation itself. I derived that part from Bcons crypto algorithms.